Unable to handle error from external batch command
I used to have a local project batch file that called IZPACK's compile.bat in an Azure Devops pipeline. There was an error with the build that didn't fail the pipeline so I added the check to fail on stderr. Now there is an error being reported that was never seen before checking for stderr,
##[error]Jul 01, 2024 11:37:50 AM com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig <init>

In order to fix the issue I thought to change from a batch file to a powershell script for error handling.
build_izpack.ps1
& "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" install.xml -b . -o "$env:userprofile\IzpackSetup.jar" -k standard

now I have tried using
try{
& "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" install.xml -b . -o "$env:userprofile\IzpackSetup.jar" -k standard
} catch {
Write-Host "This is an error"
}

as well as redirects
& "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" install.xml -b . -o "$env:userprofile\IzpackSetup.jar" -k standard 2>&1

I even used Start-Process with exit code passthrough
$A = Start-Process "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" -ArgumentList @("install.xml", "-b", ".", "-o", "$env:userprofile\IzpackSetup.jar", "-k", "standard") -Wait -passthru;$a.ExitCode
$A.ExitCode

I forget which options returned just the string of an error like above and which threw a native command error like this below.
##[error]compile.bat : Jul 01, 2024 6:32:15 AM com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig <init>
At C:\devops\eng-builder04-agent\_work\5\s\installer\build_server_compiler_powershell.ps1:49 char:1
+ & "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" install.xml -b . -o "$env:userpr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Jul 01, 2024 6:...erConfig <init>:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

but each time, the script fails with the error line and without being handled. I'm looking for what I might be doing wrong with any of the options I have already used or if there is something I am missing to handle this.
Edit:
Here is the task in the pipeline
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'installer/build_izpack.ps1'
    failOnStderr: true
    workingDirectory: 'installer'
  displayName: 'Powershell Build Windows Installer'

This step, and the error itself doesn't appear if "failOnStderr: true" is not there.

From what I understand, compile.bat is further calling, one or more times, an additional batch file, (lcp-bat), with jar files as an argument. Based upon that, we have nowhere near sufficient information to reproduce your specified problem.

@Compo lcp.bat sets a localClasspath environment variable with all jars listed in izpacks's sub directory before running the java command. So there is the possibility of errors bubbling up. Is that a possible reason the error isn't being caught in my powershell script?

How did you call the batch script using PowerShell before adding the check for stderr?

I think you could do something like this in Powershell (assuming that compile.bat does not exit with 0):
try {

  & "$env:IZPACK_HOME\bin\compile.bat" install.xml -b . -o "$env:userprofile\PinPointRTLSSetup.jar" -k standard

  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    
    Throw "This is an error"
  }
} 
catch {
  
  Throw "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}

Good luck and let me know if it helped!

Thanks, I will try this and give a response with the result.

Unfortunately it resulted in the same error,
2024-07-02T13:25:59.1402781Z IZPACK_HOME is "C:\IzPack"
2024-07-02T13:26:04.8903495Z .::  IzPack - Version 5.1.3 ::.
2024-07-02T13:26:04.8941602Z < compiler specifications version: 5.0 >
2024-07-02T13:26:04.9046392Z -> Processing  : install.xml
2024-07-02T13:26:04.9057847Z -> Output      : C:\Users\svc_azdevops\izpackSetup.jar
2024-07-02T13:26:54.7391533Z ##[error]Jul 02, 2024 6:26:04 AM com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerConfig 

Sorry @swhite, maybe I misunderstood, I just thought initially that you wanted to see the catch block trigger, I have adjusted my example to Throw inside the catch block now, that should return a proper error back to the pipeline for the task.
I suspect that is what you want? Let me know.
